# Build a custom module to inject data into Drupals Javascript global object "setting"

Tags: javascript, drupal

I am trying to build a D6 Module that executes an SQL search, and saves the data in Drupal's global settings object so my front page has this data once it is loaded.  Any ideas how to do this?

Do I need to write a hook, or template preprocess?
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can add to that object using [`drupal_add_js()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/6), for example:

```
drupal_add_js(array('my_module' => array('my_setting' => 'this_value')), 'setting');
```

will give you access to `Drupal.settings.my_module.my_setting` on the client-side.

Exactly where you put that code will depend on how your pages are structured (is this part of a form submission, is it redirecting anywhere or just rebuilding the form after submission and displaying results on the same page, etc). If you can update the question with that information I'll try to address that too.